# Run script in parallel with incremental variable

Tags: bash, python, parallelism

I would like to run a python script in parallel on several processors on the files in an `INPUTDIR`. I use the few lines below for that stuff:

```bsh
# define a function
pythonprocessing(){
   python myscript.py -i "$file" -o OUTPUTDIR -c "$var"
}

# initiate an index variable
var=0

# apply function on every file in INPUTDIR
for file in INPUTDIR/*; 
do
    var=$((var=var+1))
    pythonprocessing "$file" "$var"&
done
wait
echo check
```

Everything is working fine as long as the number of files in `INPUTDIR` does not exceed the available processors. In contrary, if the number of files does exceed it, I'll receive a `memory error`. I don't understand the reason for that because I applied the implementation above a lot of times on more files than cores without encountering any problems. How can I solve the problem?

Note that this is the first time that I also increment a variable in the for loop and I'm wondering whether this could be the problem's origin. It's necessary to increment the variable because the scripts store some temporary files and read them out again and without the variable, it would not be possible to give the files unambiguous names.

Comment: Does this error message occur already if the number of files exceeds the number of processors even by 1?

Comment: Also, are you sure about your variable increment? I think it should be `var=$((var+1))`, not `var=$((var=var+1))`...

Comment: One more files than cores is fine! Concerning var increment, ```var=$((var=var+1))``` is obviously more elegant. However, both approaches work flawless

Comment: Obviously more elegant? How? I can't even workout how it works.

Comment: So, how many more than cores will it work for?

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel is made for this kind of work:

```
# define a function
pythonprocessing(){
   file="$1"
   var="$2"
   python myscript.py -i "$file" -o OUTPUTDIR -c "$var"
}
export -f pythonprocessing
parallel pythonprocessing {} {#} ::: INPUTDIR/*

echo check
```